# Which base class to inherit if it's a common class in odoo9

Tags: python, odoo

I'm using odoo9 for my project.
In my project, there is a common excel handling class fill in the excel template and output result, and here is my question: which base class should it inherit? models.Model or http.Controller, or nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are going to create odoo normal module then you must create models.Model.
- If you are going to create odoo module which will handle post or get request from web service then you must use controller.
- If you are going to create odoo module for other module, and this module is wizard then you must use transient model and etc.
- Also if you need you can make simple class and use in your module but with your question I cant tell you more

Comment: How to create transient model?  Sometimes I want to use self.env, so I have to inherit models.Model, but I don't want to generate a table in postgresql, how can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: class my_class(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'my.class''

Comment: When you launch it it will create table in database but it will not be stored, when you close wizard table will destroyed (90% sure about that)

Comment: data from a transient model will be stored but temporary. It will be deleted by a cron job from Odoo.